# Method expects argument of type 'double *'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm trying to write some code using python wrappers for epanet which I believe are SWIG-wrapped. There is a method I need to use, as outlined below from the source. However I can't seem to get the method to accept any type of value for the 3rd argument "values:".. Anything I try I get the error: TypeError: in method 'ptrn_set', argument 3 of type 'double *'

How do I convert my value/values to 'double *' within Python? what is the solution?

Thankful for any help...

```
    """
    ptrn_set(ph, index, values, len) -> int

    Parameters
    ----------
    ph: Handle
    index: int
    values: double *
    len: int

    """
    return _toolkit.ptrn_set(ph, index, values, len)
```

Comment: What do you have right now? What is `values`?

Answer (score 0):

I found this here:
https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesnumeric.html: 
Floating point numbers are implemented using double in C

Did you try float?

Comment: doubles are one kind of floating point number in C, but there are others, e.g. `float` and `long double`

Answer (score 0):

Python itself does not support values of type `double *`.  In C, that is a pointer-to-a-double-precision-floating-point-number.  In Python, effectively every name is a pointer, but you can't have a (native) value that is a pointer.

From context, it looks like they actually want an array of doubles.  They really ought to write that as `double []`, but `double *` is compatible with it.  You could try

```
values = [1.0, 2.0]
_toolkit.ptrn_set(ph, index, values, len(values))
```

It's not very Pythonic to do that, but if it works, it works.  If that doesn't work, see if your expanet python wrappers provide a way of constructing such values.

If your expanet Python wrappers don't provide a way to construct such values, you can try the cffi library, but it's quite tricky.  I think `x = ffi.new("double[10]")` will give you an array of 10 doubles.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your effort!
 
Thus far I've tried passing:
 
x = 1.2
x = float(1.2)
x = [1.2, 2.0]
x = ffi.new("double[10]") /using the cffi library
x = ctypes.c_float([1.0,  2.0]) /using ctypes library
 
It keeps returning the same error...
 
The EPANET wrapper in question: https://github.com/OpenWaterAnalytics/epanet-python

Answer (score 0):

I know some time passed an you probably already solved it, but it might be useful for someone else.

you can use the following function to create an array that will be accepted by epanet:

```
def make_array(values):
    dbl_arr = en.doubleArray(len(values))
    for i in range(len(values)):
        dbl_arr[i] = values[i]
    return dbl_arr
```

the input is an array of float, like [1.2 , 0.8].
This assuming you imported the epanet python library as
**from epanet import toolkit as en**,
source:  https://github.com/OpenWaterAnalytics/epanet-python/issues/57